# add wheres entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to use string to increment a query but I can't find how to do it

```
string[] subNames = myWord.Split(' ');
string myRequest = "contact => ";
for(string name in subNames)
{
     myRequest += "contact.firstName.contains(" + name + ") || contact.lastName.contains(" + name + ") &&";
}
request=request.Where(myRequest).Any();
```

I can't use String type inside a Where and i can't use Where an unkown number of time. What do you advise me ?

thank you for your help !

Comment: I'm 10000% sure you can't place instructions inside strings and then try to execute them.

Since you're working with Entities, try placing an instruction inside a var, it'll be the type of iQueryable, then try to bundle them in together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `.Where` inside your loop, i.e.

```
string[] subNames = myWord.Split(' ');
foreach (string name in subNames)
{
    request=request.Where(contact =>
        contact.firstName.Contains(name) || 
        contact.lastName.Contains(name)
    );
}
var result = request.Any();
```

Comment: Will adding a where in my loop add "&&" between each where ?

Comment: You can chain where's which implies the &&, e.g. `results.Where(x => x.Size == "Large").Where(x => x.Colour == "Red");`

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of Where I can add ?

Comment: @Gromain, there is no maximum per se. The `.Where()` method returns another collection of the same type you are invocating on, which is what allows the chaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `Where(...).Any()` with `Any(...)`. You can also use enumerable functions on `subNames`.

```
var subNames = myWord.Split(' ');
var result = request.Any(contact => 
    subNames.Any(sub => 
        contact.fistName.Contains(sub) ||
        contact.lastName.Contains(sub));
```